# Missing databases error in SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a database in assets/databases and also have a class to read data from my database 
but when open database i got Missing databases error

Note: i have myDb.zip in assets/databases

this is my Class to open database:

```java
public class DB_helper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDb.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DB_helper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

}
```

and in this line i call it:

```java
 SQLiteDatabase mydb = new DB_helper(appContext).getWritableDatabase();
```

i got this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ir.dpsoft.saman, PID: 10620
    com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/myDb.db file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable
```

Comment: Do you have file write permission ?

Comment: @Swayangjit yes

Comment: Can you please post your code where you are copying your db. ?

Answer (score 0):

`SQLiteAssetHelper` just appends `.zip` or `.gz` suffixes to the base name, not replacing anything in the file path.

You can fix this either in the asset name or in code. To fix the asset, ship your database as `myDb.db.zip`, not `myDb.zip`. Or to fix the code, pass the database name as `myDb` and not `myDb.db`.